# Grails/Groovy string error

Tags: grails, groovy

I am getting the following error which I cannot seem to understand:

```
| Error 2014-07-19 02:31:31,563 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FatcaOne_0/customer/upload - parameters:
dataTypegrp: 3
fileTypegrp: 1
No signature of method: java.lang.String.negative() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: notify(), next(), normalize(), next(), normalize(). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: java.lang.String.negative() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: notify(), next(), normalize(), next(), normalize()
    Line | Method
->>  238 | doCall                         in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService$_$tt__excelIndividualFileUpload_closure16$$EOkQLTQ0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    162 | $tt__excelIndividualFileUpload in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService$$EOkQLTQ0
|    147 | upload . . . . . . . . . . . . in com.twc.fatcaone.CustomerController
|    198 | doFilter                       in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                      in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                            in java.lang.Thread
```

The line of code that this error points to reads as:

```
def (redFlags, yellowFlags) = processExistingIndividualRecordFlags(incomingRecord, recordThatAlreadyExists, params)
```

I am calling this line repeatedly in a loop and some previous few calls to it aren't causing any problem. So I’m stumped as to what/where I am doing to a `String` that seems to be causing this `String` related error.

Comment: What's the content of processExistingIndividualRecordFlags?

Comment: FileImportService is trying to call negative() on String, which does not exist. What is happening there around line 238?

Comment: As @MartinHauner said, I think you are using **-** on a parameter, assuming that incoming value is of type number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once got this error when I was trying to remove a String from a List and got my "-" and "=" backwards like this:

```
listOfStrings =- stringTobeRemoved
```

Comment: The funny thing is that the runtime doesn't delve into the function that contained the erroneous line and instead picked theline that calls the erroneous line containing function. That's what made it hard to navigate to the error.